# Tomcat 8 Manager, HTML and Text running, access from ANT Connection Refused

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, ant, intellij-idea

first time poster here.  I'm setting up a new Tomcat 8 instance and I'm trying to utilize tomcat 8 manager from my build.xml script (via IntelliJ).  I'm using the list command to test the connection, but want I really want is stop/start/redeploy/etc.  I've tested both manager/text/ and manager/html succesfully.

[Windows 7 box]

Code snippets incoming 
tomcat-users.xml:

```
   <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script" />
    <role rolename="manager-gui" />
    <user username="script" password="test" roles="admin-gui,manager-script"/>
    <user username="manager" password="test" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui"/>
```

build.xml:

```
<target name="list"
   description="List installed applications on servlet container">
    <echo>List Using:(${manager.url})  [${manager.username}|${manager.password}]</echo>
    <list    url="${manager.url}"
        username="${manager.username}"
        password="${manager.password}"/>

  </target>
```

Output from 'list' task from IntelliJ:

```
List Using:(http://localhost:8080/manager/text)  [script|test]
Task: list
C:\apps\myapp\build.xml:478: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:269)
...etc
```

Every tutorial I go to talks about setting up Tomcat-Users.xml or opening port 8443 for the manager, but I haven't seen an answer for what to do if you have confirmed manager is running (it is) but build.xml/ANT seem have trouble getting authorized.

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

- Have you actually confirmed that manager app is deployed to the `/manager` context? It's only deployed by default on the default host. For other virtual hosts, this is something you must do manually. Try visiting `http://localhost:8080/manager` with your web browser. Try logging in with the `manager-gui` user.
- Does your tomcat instance run more than one virtual host? If so, it's possible that your ant task is hitting a different virtual host than one you want. Check your `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml` file's `<Engine>` and `<Host>` elements. Does `<Engine>` contain just one `<Host>`? If it contains multiple hosts, whate are the `name` attributes set to? What is the `defaultHost` attribute of `<Engine>` set to?

Comment: I tried visiting http://localhost:8080/manager and firefox took me to http://localhost:8080/manager/html where I logged in with my manager user successfully and saw the manager dashboard. (If I go to manager/text, [after clearing session] I see failed command until I give it one in the url)  So that looks good to me.   I haven't modified server.xml, but I'm checking it now anyway... I have one <engine> entry (<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">) and it contains one <host> entry: <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">